# Loop in ajax, ordering function executions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I want to use jquery for checking sites servers one by one and if the server is ok start grabbing pages.

But in the following code, the loop execute at the first and 2 message appears at the first lines:

```
start analyzing site 1
start analyzing site 2

start grabbing site 1
start grabbing site 2
...
```

How I can change this to:

```
start analyzing site 1
start grabbing site 1
...

start analyzing site 2
start grabbing site 1
...
```

I am new in Jquery, but I have read about **promise** and deferrals but could not write the correct code.

I tested this code by `async:false`. It solves the problem, But I don't want to use this approach (You know the reason).

```
new_links_arr() = array('site1', 'site2');

function check_server(response) {

  var new_links_c = new_links_arr.length;

  for (var n = 0; n < new_links_c; n++) {
    var this_link = new_links_arr[n];

    if (this_link.length > 5) {
      $("#responds").append("<hr/> start analyzing site:  " + this_link + "");

      var myData = 'mod=chk_srv&url=' + encodeURIComponent(this_link) + '&mk_rds_dir=1';

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: my_url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: myData,
        cache: false,
        success: grab_site,
        error: end_error
      });

    }
  }

}

function grab_site(response) {
  $("#responds").append(" " + response.the_msg + " ");

  var status = response.status;
  if (status == 1) {
    $("#responds").append(" start grabbing site ");
    var myData = 'mod=chk_home&url=' + encodeURIComponent(response.url);
    $("#Loding_info").html("Get Homapage and Detecting software from " + response.url);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: my_url,
      dataType: "json",
      data: myData,
      success: parse_jdata,
      error: end_error
    })
  } else {
    $("#responds").append("stop");
    end_ajax();
  }

}
```

Comment: Instead of using a `for` loop, start the second test in the `success` function of the first, and so on.

Comment: I used success. But it dose not solve the problem. (Maybe I had mistakes in coding. )

Comment: What does `new_links_arr() = array('site1', 'site2');` do? You can't assign to a function call, and there's no `array()` function in JS.

Comment: Seems like that should be `var new_links_arr = ['site1', 'site2'];`

Comment: What is the `response` argument to `check_server` for? You never use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start the next test after you finish processing the previous one.

```
var new_links_arr = ['site1', 'site2'];
var new_links_index = 0;

function check_server() {

  if (new_links_index >= new_links_arr.length) {
    return;
  }

  var this_link = new_links_arr[new_links_index];

  if (this_link.length > 5) {
    $("#responds").append("<hr/> start analyzing site:  " + this_link + "");

    var myData = {
      mod: 'chk_srv',
      url: this_link,
      mk_rds_dir: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: my_url,
      dataType: "json",
      data: myData,
      cache: false,
      success: grab_site,
      error: end_error
    });

  }

}

function grab_site(response) {
  $("#responds").append(" " + response.the_msg + " ");

  var status = response.status;
  if (status == 1) {
    $("#responds").append(" start grabbing site ");
    var myData = {
      mod: 'chk_home',
      url: response.url
    };
    $("#Loding_info").html("Get Homepage and Detecting software from " + response.url);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: my_url,
      dataType: "json",
      data: myData,
      success: parse_jdata,
      error: end_error
    })
  } else {
    $("#responds").append("stop");
    end_ajax();
  }

}

function parse_jdata(response) {
  // do your processing
  // ...
  new_links_index++;
  check_server();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code was long (more than 10 functions). So I cut some piece of it and made a new array (The real array is made by php from previous response and post by json). This is the reason of mistakes in the code.

The idea by Barmar (incrementing the array index in the final function) was helpful. I changed my code and it is working nice now. Thank you for your help.

I added the new function for sending sites one by one to the next functions:

```
    function walk_in_links_arr(new_links_arr2) 
    {
        if (new_links_index >= new_links_arr2.length) 
        {
            //alert(' new_links_index11 = ' + new_links_index);
            $("#responds").append("all sites checking done.  ");
            pass_response_final();
        }

        var this_link = new_links_arr2[new_links_index];
        //alert(' new_links_index22 = ' + new_links_index);
        //alert (this_link);
        if(this_link.length>5)
        {
                $("#responds").append(" start checking  " + this_link + " ");


                var myData = 'mod=chk_srv&url='+ encodeURIComponent(this_link)+'&mk_rds_dir=1';

                $.ajax({
                type: "GET", 
                url: my_url,
                dataType:"json",
                data:myData, 
                cache: false,
                success:grab_site,
                error:end_error
                });
        }
        else
        {
            new_links_index++;
            walk_in_links_arr(new_links_arr);           
        }
   }
```